# Govendor as type error

Tags: go, vendor, govendor

Getting an error:  cannot use *company/model as type *vendor/company/model

Flat Vendor structure : vendor/company/model

The files import "company/model"

Answer (score 2):

You have a package `company/model` that is both vendored (under `vendor/`) and in your global $GOPATH, you additionally have an unvendored package that your package depends on that depends on `company/model`. So your package and the unvendored package are both trying to use the type company/modal but finding them in different places. The solution is to vendor the package that is not vendored.

Answer (score 0):

delete the packages under the vendor directory

Answer (score 0):

Follow GarMan's [explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39783119/6097773), running command `govendor add +e` works.